# Attached Property Values are not passed to the View - style for first/last item of list

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

My intention is to define a dependency property `Position` for list-elements to style them different if they are on the edge.

I have a dependency property (along with its default get and set methods that are not shown):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Position", 
    typeof(Position), 
    typeof(ClientView),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      Position.Normal));
```

a TabControl:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Items" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItem}"/>
```

and a template for those TabItems:

```
    <Style x:Key="TabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        ... <Setter Property="Template"> <Setter.Value>
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Bd">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock 
Text="{Binding Position, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
       AncestorType={x:Type client:ClientView}}}"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
     </Grid>
     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="client:ClientView.Position" Value="Last">
          <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,0,0,4"/>
        </Trigger>
     ...
```

On the codebehind of my `ClientView` class, i fill those properties when the items generator tells me that he created those tabitems:

```
var gen = Items.ItemContainerGenerator;
gen.StatusChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
   if (gen.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
   {
      var cnt = Items.Items.Count;
      if (cnt > 0)
      {
         if (cnt == 1)
         {
            gen.ContainerFromItem(Items.Items[0])
               .SetValue(PositionProperty, Position.Normal);
         }
         else
         {
            gen.ContainerFromItem(Items.Items[0])
               .SetValue(PositionProperty, Position.First);
            if (cnt > 2)
            {
               for (int i = 1; i < cnt - 2; i++)
               {
                  gen.ContainerFromItem(Items.Items[i])
                     .SetValue(PositionProperty, Position.Normal);
               }
            }
            gen.ContainerFromItem(Items.Items[cnt - 1])
               .SetValue(PositionProperty, Position.Last);
         }
      }
   }
};
```

When i run this code, i can debug those event and see the correct values are set, but they never appear in the view. The text of the textbox always shows "Normal" which is the default value.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try a DataTrigger in your Style, instead of a Trigger  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Property

Comment: Tried `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding client:Position}" Value="Last">` also with `{Binding Position, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type client:ClientView}}}`. Both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you bind bind the `TextBlock.Text`property like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding
    Path=(ClientView.Position),
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
```

since the attached property is set on the styled TabItem, i.e. the `TemplatedParent`.

EDIT: What if you also set the `Border.CornerRadius` property by a binding with a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that converts from Position to an appropriate CorderRadius value:

```
<Border CornerRadius="{Binding
    Path=(ClientView.Position),
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},
    Converter={StaticResource PositionToCornerRadiusConverter}}" />
```

Comment: This works partially. The TextBox is showing "First" and "Last", but the corner radius style is not applied. I had a guess, that it might be y type problem and changed the `Position` enum to a string, but that was also not successfull.

    `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(client:ClientView.Position), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Value="First">
       <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="Bd" Value="4,0,0,0"/></DataTrigger>`

Comment: Yes, in the `IsSelected` trigger, but there is no "reset"
`<Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="Bd" Value="4,0,0,4"/>`
Edit: just tried to remove the line, but nothing changed.

Comment: Ill try if it works, but its kinda suboptimal since the cornerradius should also depend on the IsSelected property in another trigger.

Comment: If it depends on two properties `ClientView.Position` and `IsSelected` you could easily use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx).

Comment: Ok, it works! :) But: What a HEAVY solution for such a simple task. I removed both data triggers, so that only the CornerRadius binding and the IsSelected trigger are active. The coverter works as expected, and when the IsSelected trigger hits, the cornerradius is overwritten.

Comment: You're initial approach with a trigger on ClientView.Position which sets CornerRadius is certainly less heavy, but that's only true as long as there is no second trigger that also affects CornerRadius. The combination is what makes it complicated.

Comment: But for my understanding of Triggers, this absolutely normal and common for almost every style to have that. How does it make things complicated?

Comment: As i've understood your problem you wanted to set CornerRadius to a value that depends on a combination of IsSelected and Position. But a normal trigger can only react on one of these properties and never knows about the other.

Comment: I think there is something like `<MultiTrigger/>`

Comment: Yes, that would perhaps be an alternative.